# Delay SwiftUI view rendering until Published object finishes loading

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I am trying to build an app using SwiftUI, and I've created a class responsible for performing an API request and decoding the response into a `weatherResponse` object, and have annotated this object as `@Published` within this class.

In my view, I have instantiated this class using the `@StateObject` annotation. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619917/why-arent-my-swift-network-requests-working), this should be the correct way of observing the `weatherResponse` object within my view so that it automatically updates.

However, when my view loads the instance of `WeatherNetworking` hasn't even been initialized, and so the first reference to the object published within that class results in a nil value access.

```
struct MainWeatherView: View {
    
    @StateObject var weatherNetworking = WeatherNetworking()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: weatherNetworking.getConditionName(weatherID: (weatherNetworking.weatherResponse!.current.weather[0].id))) // weatherResponse is nil
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio( contentMode: .fit)
                .scaleEffect(0.75)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Temperature")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                    Text("Humidity")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                    ...
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Text("\(weatherNetworking.weatherResponse!.current.temp, specifier: "%.2f") °F")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                    Text("\(weatherNetworking.weatherResponse!.current.humidity, specifier: "%.0f") %")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.weatherNetworking.getMainWeather()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class WeatherNetworking: ObservableObject {
    
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @Published var weatherResponse: WeatherResponse?
    
    func getMainWeather() {
        print("Location:", locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude)
        if let loc = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?appid=redacted&exclude=minutely&units=imperial&lat=\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)&lon=\(locationManager.lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: loc) { data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.weatherResponse = results
                            }
                            print("weatherResponse was succesfully updated")
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error!)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    } 
}
```

None of the print statements within `getMainWeather()` execute which leads me to believe that the view is attempting to assign values before the function is called.  How can I delay the assignment of these values within my view until after the `onAppear()` method finishes? it is worth noting that just as `MainWeatherView` depends upon the instantiation and asynchronous calls in `WeatherNetworking`, so too `WeatherNetworking` depends upon an instance of `LocationManager`.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?
    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation?

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make dependent views conditional, like

```
VStack {
   if let response = weatherNetworking.weatherResponse {
        Image(systemName: weatherNetworking.getConditionName(weatherID: (response.current.weather[0].id))) // weatherResponse is nil
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio( contentMode: .fit)
            .scaleEffect(0.75)
            .padding()
   }
   // .. other code
```